# In Angular2, if I have a dynamic dropdown with only 1 option in it, how do I autoselect the one and only option when the options are set?

Tags: angular, select, html-select, dropdown

I'm an Angular2 newbie and hoping someone can help me. I'm taking over a project already started by someone else.

I have a bunch on interdependent dropdowns, and when an option is selected in one, it affects which options are available to choose from in others. This interdependency works fine at the moment.

My question is, some of these dropdowns occasionally have only 1 option in them. When this happens, I'd like to be able to just auto select that 1 option available, and then run an `onChange()` event so that the rest of the dropdowns can update themselves accordingly to that item being selected.

I'm not sure how to do this though.

The app is complicated and I'm not sure I totally understand it yet. It looks  like each dropdown is in it's own form with a `[formGroup]` defined. The state in the app and all dropdowns is saved using the `ngrx/store` and this is what is used to check to see if a dropdown is selected or not (`this.room` in the code is a store). I think what happens is when ther user selected a dropdown, and event is broacast out to update the store with the selected option, then a function is called to reupdate all the dropdowns which is dependent on each other. These dropdpwn check the store to see what the `id` is of the selected option and set that option with the matching is as selected... I think.

Here's a snippet of code for how the  forms are coded:

```
<form [formGroup]="this.formService.JunctionForm">
        <label>Junction</label>
        <select class="form-control" #topelement3 formControlName="fj" elementRequired (change)="reportElement('Junction', this.formService.JunctionForm.value.fj)">
        <option *ngFor="let option of generateAllPaths(junctions.horizontalFlankingJunctions.Junction, 'Junction', 'selectedJunction')" [ngValue]="option.ID" [selected]="option.ID==this.room.Junction?.ID ? this.room.Junction.ID : 0">{{option[description]}} </option>
        </select>   
    </form>
```

I hope this helps!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide code showing what you have and how you have it set up?

Comment: We need more code for a specific solution, but generally what you should do is use the [selected] property on the dropdowns and update it in whatever function is setting the available options.

Comment: I'm not sure how to give you a small example of what I have set up as the app is large and complicated with lots of code pieces in several p[lace. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it all. I've updated my question with a bit more set up explanation and a code snippet if that helps. (I hope it does!)